# C# Set windows service to run infinite times

Tags: c#

I have a windows service in a server, that inserts to database. I want it to run every hour, infinite times (until i stop it). It runs a few times, and then it stops. 
There is no pattern to it as far as I have seen so far. If i set it to every 5 seconds it runs many times, if i set it to every 1 hour it runs only a few times, etc. 
I would prefer not a solution with task scheduler, but modifying the code accordingly or telling me where the mistake it.

I do not know if it is a problem to the code or the server. What should I change?
 I have 2 cs files:

Currently at 100 seconds for testing.
Commented out parts that did not work:
Service1.cs

```
  static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    /// 


    static System.Timers.Timer timer;

    //static void Main(string[] args)
    //{
    //    var periodTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
    //    timer = new System.Timers.Timer(periodTimeSpan.TotalSeconds);
    //    timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
    //    timer.Start();
    //}

    private static void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Do some stuff

        timer.Start();
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Service1 myService = new Service1();
        myService.OnDebug();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);

        //// 0, ,0, 10 seconds. adjust accordingly.
        //TimeSpan interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);

        //for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        //{

        //    Thread.Sleep(interval);
        //}

        var periodTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100);
        timer = new System.Timers.Timer(periodTimeSpan.TotalSeconds);
        timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
        timer.Start();

        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
        {
            new Service1()
        }
        ;
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);



    }
```

Program.cs (inserting to database)

```
    var startTimeSpan = TimeSpan.Zero;
        var periodTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100);
        var timer = new System.Threading.Timer((e) =>
         {

//insert data to database//

        } ,null, startTimeSpan, periodTimeSpan);
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to have the program run all the time? Why not use something like Windows' scheduler to start the program every hour, let it do it's work and finish?

Comment: Services are slightly harder to debug. Since it does repeat the action a few times before stopping, my bet is that you get an exception that is not handled and the service just stops. Try adding some try/catch in your code and / or do more logging and see what happens.

Comment: Yes I am sure. No windows scheduler.

Comment: Check for a crash in event viewer

Comment: No crashes. It just stops. Any advice on how to modify         System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);